# Add class to this element outside of parent div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to target a specific parent of an element and then add a class to it with jQuery. Example:

```js
$('.disable-link').click(function(e) {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parents('.item').find('.title').addClass('disabled');
  
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <div class="title">Thing 1</div>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="disable-link" href="#">Click to Disable Thing 1</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">Thing 2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="disable-link" href="#">Click to Disable Thing 2</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">Thing 3</div>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="disable-link" href="#">Click to Disable Thing 3</a>
</div>
```

I thought that by using `.parents('.item')` it would go all the way up the chain to that specific `item` class with `this` and target that specific one, but for some reason it's not.

I've tried using `parent().parent().find('.title')` but that ends up adding the `disabled` class to all of the titles and not just the one.
I have a feeling that it something simple, but I can't wrap my head around the specific inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements with class `.item` are not a parents of `.disable-link` elements so you should target the parent `div` first then get the previous `.item` using the `.prev()` method like:

```
$('.disable-link').click(function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parents('div').prev('.item').find('.title').addClass('disabled');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.disable-link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parents('div').prev('.item').find('.title').addClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
.disabled{
   background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <div class="title">Thing 1</div>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="disable-link" href="#">Click to Disable Thing 1</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">Thing 2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="disable-link" href="#">Click to Disable Thing 2</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">Thing 3</div>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="disable-link" href="#">Click to Disable Thing 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense. I knew I was missing another step up somewhere. Thnx!